# Filtering in Pig

Tags: hadoop, filtering, apache-pig

I am trying to do a filter for a relation in pig, I need all those records in which there is an occurrence of third field in the first field string.

I tried with:
(Assume my source relation is SRC)

```
Filtered= FILTER SRC BY $0 matches 'CONCAT(".*",$2,".")';
DUMP Filtered;
```

There is no syntax error but I am not getting any output for Filtered.

Answer (score 4):

Pig's `CONCAT` takes only two arguments. See the documentation at http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#concat

I'm not sure why it isn't complaining at runtime, but you're going to want to string together two `CONCAT` statements, like

```
CONCAT(".*", CONCAT($2, "."))
```

to get the string you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the CONCAT is resolving to what you're expecting, more so the matches is probably trying to match the entire unevalutated string `CONCAT(".*",$2,".")`, which is why you are not getting any results

Can you break this out into two statements, the first where you create a field containing the evalulated content of the CONCAT, and a second to perform the matches operation:

```
TMP = FOREACH SRC GENERATE $0, CONCAT(".*",$2,".");
Filtered = FILTER TMP BY $0 matches $1;
DUMP Filtered;
```

Or something like that (completely untested)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have some syntax errors

- As noted by A. Leistra, CONCAT only takes two arguments.
- "." at the end should be ".*" if you want double sided wildcards
- FILTER statement prefers parenthesis around the argument
- Pig has a lot of weird edge cases involving double quotes, so just use single when you can

`Filtered= FILTER SRC BY ($0 matches CONCAT('.*', CONCAT($2, '.*')));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Filtered= FILTER SRC BY $0 matches '(.*)$2(.*)';

DUMP Filtered;
```

If the third field contains the first field then that results will be filtered.
This is done by using Regex.